# Java (Eclipse) Can't seem to handle my large iterations! SPOILERS FOR EULER'S 7TH

Tags: java, eclipse

Here is my code for Euler's 7th problem.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int desiredMax = 1000000;
    int maxNumberOfTerms = 0;
    int maxTerm = 0;
    for(int startingNumber = 1; startingNumber<=desiredMax;startingNumber++) {
        int numberOfTerms = 1;
        int currentNumber = startingNumber;
        while(currentNumber!= 1) {
            if(currentNumber%2 == 0) {
                currentNumber = currentNumber/2;
                numberOfTerms++;
            } else {
                currentNumber = (3 * currentNumber) + 1;
                numberOfTerms++;
            }
        }
        if(numberOfTerms > maxNumberOfTerms) {
            maxNumberOfTerms = numberOfTerms;
            maxTerm = startingNumber;
        }

    }
    System.out.print(maxNumberOfTerms + " " + maxTerm);
}
```

}

When I test on 100,000 the code works properly, but when I boot it up to one million, it stops.  Any ideas?

I added print statements to print every 10,0000 iterations, and it gets to about 110,000 before mysteriously stopping.  I dunno if I'm getting any exceptions, or if I am, I don't know how to check, sorry!

EDIT:  I tried again with recursion, but still have the same problem.

```
    package Euler;
public class Euler14 {
    static int desiredMax = 1000000;
    static int maxTerm = 0;
    static int maxNumberOfTerms = 0;
    static int currentNumber = 0;
    static int numberOfTerms = 0;
    public static void doMath(int startingNumber) {
        if(startingNumber == 1) {
            System.out.print( maxTerm + " " + maxNumberOfTerms);
        }
        else {
            currentNumber = desiredMax;
            while(currentNumber!= 1) {
                if(currentNumber%2 == 0) {
                    currentNumber = currentNumber/2;
                    numberOfTerms++;
                } else {
                    currentNumber = (3 * currentNumber) + 1;
                    numberOfTerms++;
                }
            }
            numberOfTerms++;
            if(numberOfTerms > maxNumberOfTerms) {
                maxNumberOfTerms = numberOfTerms;
                maxTerm = startingNumber;
            }
            desiredMax--;
            doMath(desiredMax);

        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        doMath(desiredMax);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? What do you mean *it stops*? Does it throw an error or does the code just stop processing? If it just stops, is it always at the same number?

Comment: Could you give us the exact `Exception` you're getting?

Comment: Honestly looks to me like a Big-O problem. Maybe it doesn't stop, but just takes too long to compute. Try adding print statements. Do you get an exception? It could also have run out of memory.

Comment: Updated to the best of my knowledge.  What do I do to fix it if it runs out of memory?

Comment: It means you need a better solution! Those problems are specifically designed to discourage brute-force O(n^2) solutions.

Comment: Thanks Matt, but we are newer Computer science students, so in this situation, I dunno if we would be expected to know how to do it any other way:p

Feel free to explain the way that I would better handle this!

Comment: Hint: Save your results in a data structure that allows you _O_(1) access, so that future iterations don't have to recompute the number terms if they encounter a number that's already been solved.  Also, watch out for overflow in `currentNumber`.

Comment: I believe `numberOfTerms` is overflowing the maximum value of int.

Answer (score 2):

Your `currentNumber` variable is overflowing the `int` data type, becoming a negative number, and causing your code to enter an infinite loop.

To fix the problem, declare the variable like so (in your original looping code):

```
long currentNumber = startingNumber;
```

Now the calculation can complete very quickly for `int desiredMax = 1000000` (one million).

When `currentNumber` is data type `int`, here is the progression of values that result in the infinite loop (read top to bottom, then left to right):

```
 113383  1379177   2795998  204058582 -1812855948 -102088288  -4435 -248
 340150  4137532   1397999  102029291  -906427974  -51044144 -13304 -124
 170075  2068766   4193998  306087874  -453213987  -25522072  -6652  -62
 510226  1034383   2096999  153043937 -1359641960  -12761036  -3326  -31
 255113  3103150   6290998  459131812  -679820980   -6380518  -1663  -92
 765340  1551575   3145499  229565906  -339910490   -3190259  -4988  -46
 382670  4654726   9436498  114782953  -169955245   -9570776  -2494  -23
 191335  2327363   4718249  344348860  -509865734   -4785388  -1247  -68
 574006  6982090  14154748  172174430  -254932867   -2392694  -3740  -34
 287003  3491045   7077374   86087215  -764798600   -1196347  -1870  -17
 861010 10473136   3538687  258261646  -382399300   -3589040   -935  -50
 430505  5236568  10616062  129130823  -191199650   -1794520  -2804  -25
1291516  2618284   5308031  387392470   -95599825    -897260  -1402  -74
 645758  1309142  15924094  193696235  -286799474    -448630   -701  -37
 322879   654571   7962047  581088706  -143399737    -224315  -2102 -110
 968638  1963714  23886142  290544353  -430199210    -672944  -1051  -55
 484319   981857  11943071  871633060  -215099605    -336472  -3152 -164
1452958  2945572  35829214  435816530  -645298814    -168236  -1576  -82
 726479  1472786  17914607  217908265  -322649407     -84118   -788  -41
2179438   736393  53743822  653724796  -967948220     -42059   -394 -122
1089719  2209180  26871911  326862398  -483974110    -126176   -197  -61
3269158  1104590  80615734  163431199  -241987055     -63088   -590 -182
1634579   552295  40307867  490293598  -725961164     -31544   -295  -91
4903738  1656886 120923602  245146799  -362980582     -15772   -884 -272
2451869   828443  60461801  735440398  -181490291      -7886   -442 -136
7355608  2485330 181385404  367720199  -544470872      -3943   -221  -68
3677804  1242665  90692702 1103160598  -272235436     -11828   -662
1838902  3727996  45346351  551580299  -136117718      -5914   -331
 919451  1863998 136039054 1654740898   -68058859      -2957   -992
2758354   931999  68019527  827370449  -204176576      -8870   -496
```

Note that the last value, at index 236, is the same as the value at index 218.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of iterations try using a recursive function approach to solve this , using brute force algorithms will eventually fail to compute a big input .

Comment: Tried recursion,  still no worx:(

Comment: I think gknicker has given you the answer, you are overflowing the int type with your currentnumber ,:)